# color row tableview not change javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a tableView with text message change color in term of a type message. 
I have the following code :

```
tableViewErreur.setRowFactory(param -> new TableRow<BoErreur>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(BoErreur paramT, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(paramT, empty);
            if (!isEmpty() && paramT != null) {
                switch (paramT.getNiveauErreur()) {
                case 0:
                    setId(ConstantsUI.CSS_ERREUR_INFO);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    setId(ConstantsUI.CSS_ERREUR);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                tableViewErreur.refresh();
            }
        }
    });
```

And I have the following code to have a wrap text in my cell :

```
tableColumnErreur.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<BoErreur, String>, TableCell<BoErreur, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<BoErreur, String> call(TableColumn<BoErreur, String> arg0) {
            return new TableCell<BoErreur, String>() {
                private Text text;

                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!isEmpty()) {
                        text = new Text(item.toString());
                        text.setWrappingWidth(tableColumnErreur.getWidth());
                        this.setWrapText(true);

                        setGraphic(text);

                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

The problem is that my second code remove the cell's color. And I need to make :

```
switch (paramT.getNiveauErreur())
```

in the RowFactory to determinate my row's color.

Help please,

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant CSS?

Comment: Found !! I change my css to aplicate one color at all child :  '#info *'

Comment: BTW: You shouldn't wonder, if "ghost items" are left in your table, since you never set back the look of a cell to its original state, if it becomes empty...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a different colors in odd and even rows you need only to use this code in your **.css** file.

```
 .table-row-cell:odd{
    //add color here
}

.table-row-cell:even{
    //add color here
}
```